# How to read an audio file? Which method should I use?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, jmf

I have a panel with 2 buttons. When I click on the button 1, I'd simply like to read an audio file (a .WAV in that case). Then, when I click on the button 2, I'd like to stop the music.

I do some research, but I'm a little confused about the different methods.
Which one is the best in my case ? Can someone explains the difference between AudioClip, JavaSound and JavaMediaFramework please ?

I've also try an example, but it contains errors.

Here is my **Main.class** :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
           SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/Ma musique/Échantillons de musique/Symphonie n° 9 de Beethoven (scherzo).wma");
           InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(player.getSamples()); 
           player.play(stream);
    }
}
```

Here is my **SoundPlayer.class** :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundPlayer 
{
    private AudioFormat format;
    private byte[] samples;
    /**
     * 
     * @param filename le lien vers le fichier song (URL ou absolute path)
     */
    public SoundPlayer(String filename)
    {
        try
        {
            AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename));
            format = stream.getFormat();
            samples = getSamples(stream);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public byte[] getSamples()
    {
        return samples;
    }

    public byte[] getSamples(AudioInputStream stream)
    {
        int length = (int)(stream.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize());
        byte[] samples = new byte[length];
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
        try
        {
            in.readFully(samples);
        }
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return samples;
    }

    public void play(InputStream source)
    {
        int bufferSize = format.getFrameSize() * Math.round(format.getSampleRate() / 10);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        SourceDataLine line;
        try
        {
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            line = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format, bufferSize);
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        line.start();

        try
        {
            int numBytesRead = 0;
            while (numBytesRead != -1)
            {
                numBytesRead = source.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (numBytesRead != -1)
                    line.write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        line.drain();
        line.close();
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT** :

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at SoundPlayer.<init>(SoundPlayer.java:19)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

In advance, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem.
In my case, the use of **[JAVAZOOM](http://www.javazoom.net/index.shtml)** librairy is good.

Here is a sample, which only play an audio file when launching (no graphical part)

```
public class Sound 
{   
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private AdvancedPlayer player = null;

    public Sound(String path) throws Exception 
    {
        InputStream in = (InputStream)new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
        player = new AdvancedPlayer(in);
    }

    public Sound(String path,PlaybackListener listener) throws Exception 
    {
        InputStream in = (InputStream)new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
        player = new AdvancedPlayer(in);
        player.setPlayBackListener(listener);
    }

    public void play() throws Exception
    {
        if (player != null) 
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            player.play();
        }
    }

    public void play(int begin,int end) throws Exception 
    {
        if (player != null) 
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            player.play(begin,end);
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception 
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            player.stop();
            isPlaying = false;

        }
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() 
    {
        return isPlaying;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("lecture de son");
        try 
        {
            Sound sound = new Sound("C:/Documents and Settings/cngo/Bureau/Stage-Save/TCPIP_AndroidJava/TCPIP_V6_Sound/OpeningSuite.mp3");
            System.out.println("playing : " + sound.isPlaying());
            sound.play();
            System.out.println("playing : " + sound.isPlaying());
        } 
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Thanks to @murtaza.webdev for his answers !

Answer (score 1):

That exception will stay. *.wma files are not supported by standard.

Simplest solution would be to use *.wav files or other supported files

You can get more info on:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info

Answer (score 1):

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/" + 
  "Documents/Ma musique/Échantillons de musique/" + 
   "Symphonie n° 9 de Beethoven (scherzo).wma")
```

Ah, WMA.  Great format, Java (Standard Edition) does not provide a Service Provider Interface that supports it.

You will either need to supply an SPI to allow Java Sound to support it, or use a different API.  I don't know of any APIs that provide support for WMA.  Can you encode it in a different format?

See the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for a way to support MP3, but it requires the MP3 SPI from JMF.

Answer (score 0):

Write down the full path of your music file it will works

Comment: When I write the full path, there is an other error. Have you got any idea please ?